# what does 'cd $_' mean?

Tags: bash

I have seen this command in a tutorial to create a new directory:

```
mkdir my-new-project && cd $_
```

I know `mkdir my-new-project` command is used to create a new directory, but what does `cd $_` do?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

`$_` expands to the last argument to the previous **simple command*** or to previous command if it had no arguments.

```
mkdir my-new-project && cd $_
```

^ Here you have a command made of two **simple commands**. The last argument to the first one is `my-new-project` so `$_` in the second **simple command** will expand to `my-new-project`.

To give another example:

```
echo a b; echo $_
#Will output:
#a b
#b
```

In any case, `mkdir some_dir && cd $_` is a very common combo. If you get tired of typing it, I think it's a good idea to make it a function:

```
mkdircd() {
  #Make path for each argument and cd into the last path 
  mkdir -p "$@" && cd "$_" 
}
```

---

*
The [bash manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) defines a **simple command** as *"a sequence of optional variable assignments followed by blank-separated words and redirections, and terminated by a **control operator.** "* where **control operator** refers to one of `|| & && ; ;; ( ) | |& <newline>`.

In practice`$_` works like I've described but only with `||`, `&&`, `;`, or *newline* as the control operator.

Answer (score 9):

*7. How to create directory and switch to it using single command. As you might already know, the && operator is used for executing multiple commands, and $_ expands to the last argument of the previous command.*

Quickly, if you want, you can create a directory and also move to that directory by using a single command. To do this, run the following command:

```
$ mkdir [dir-name] && cd $_
```

For those coming from Udacity's Version Control with Git,  HowToForge offers a great explanation, [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-cd-command/#-how-to-create-directory-and-switch-to-it-using-single-command).

Comment: One usage example is `git clone https://github.com/udacity/course-git-blog-project blog-project && cd $_`. This will clone a repository and open inside the newly created directory.